# Yii button with property submit - is not working

Tags: button, yii

Yesterday it was working. After many changes (but not with it template) - it's not.
Yii generates button as usually, but now by clicking it does nothing.

```
<?= CHtml::button('Sell', array(
        'submit' => CController::createUrl('product/selll', array('productID' => $data->id)),
        'style' => 'width:80px',
    )); ?>
```

Maybe i have found the problem - it is because jquery.yiiactiveform.js is not loading automaticly. Why it's not loading any more?

I have found solution. The problem is Yii form above, i've comment input text field, than no one Yii::button is working at all.
This is a code of form above:

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'searform',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
    ),
    'action' => array("user/searchForm"),
        ));?>
!!!!If i comment this textField - no one CHtml::button dont work.!!!!!
<?php  echo $form->textField($search, 

'product',array('width'=>'179px','height'=>'17px','value'=>$value,'save'=>$value));  ?>

    <? /*
<div id="srcBtnWrap">
      <?= CHtml::submitButton('',array('id'=>'srcBtn')); ?>                
</div> */ ?> 

<? //= CHtml::submitButton('go'); ?>  


<?    
    $this->endWidget();
?>
```

Is it Yii bug, or i do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

jquery.yii.js should be loaded. If it is loaded - check JS console for errors.
Check if your action does not use die() or exit()

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled client validation. Please, check errors and give us model fields (rules)

```
'enableClientValidation' => true,
'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
'clientOptions' => array(
    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
),
```